# Best way to store user's data for my app?

Tags: android

I'm developing the first app I would like to release on the play store, and I can't seem to figure out what would be the best way to store data.

User's will input a lot of numbers, which will be used to create different type of graphs. For that reason I need to be sure the data will never be lost, even if they use a new/different Android device. At first I was thinking about a database, but I'm still not sure if my app will be popular enough for me to host a database and spend cash, so I figured it wasn't the best option. Plus, it would require users to create an account.

After some thought I thought I could give the user's the option to either not create an account (but might lose their data in the long run) or create an account but I would still need to maintain a database.

Someone told me they hate creating accounts and said I could just use the Google Drive API for Android. I was looking at the doc and looking at some examples but it is a bit confusing. I would like to read/write/update a sheet, but I can't even seem to find examples on how to do that. There would also be Dropbox.

What would be the best option, in my case, to store data?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think what suits you best would be Google's [Cloud Save](https://developers.google.com/games/services/android/cloudsave), I've never used it but it sounds like it will suit you best!

Answer (score 0):

I'd go with Google Drive. I use it on my app. You have no cost, and almost every Android user has a Google Drive account. Keep looking and you will find good tutorials about it.

Or you could use also Parse. Very easy to work with. And free until a certain usage limit. www.parse.com